# Schedule airflow DAG as per user time

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG in which will be used by many users and each user can give any schedule_interval parameter from an api.
It can be 5 mins, daily, weekly, etc. Now I want my DAG to run as in a scheduled manner as specified by the user. it should pick up schedule_interval parameter externally. Is there any way to read it from a config file or any other way?

Comment: Following on this

Comment: You could start your DAG every 5 minutes and begins it with a ShortCircuitOperator. This operator would read a schedule_interval from somewhere (SQL table, S3, whatever) and if the read hour is the same as the execution, it will continue the dag, otherwise the dag would end.

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás would it be possible to give command line args and read it from there? while running this DAG? https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-airflow/externally-triggered-dags-apache-airflow/read#triggering_DAG
this says there is an api available to run DAG externally.